# How to insert an entry in SQLite ORM with a composite key

Tags: c++, sqlite, orm

I using the [SQLite ORM](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm) library for using SQLite in my program and I have table like below:

```cpp
auto storage = make_storage("test_remove.sqlite",
                            make_table("objects",
                                       make_column("key_part_1",
                                                   &Object::key_part_1),
                                       make_column("key_part_2",
                                                   &Object::key_part_2),
                                       make_column("name",
                                                   &Object::name),
                                       primary_key(&Object::key_part_1, &Object::key_part_2)));
```

That, as you can see, this table have a composite key (`key_part_1` and `key_part_2`). When I create an instance from `Object` like below,

```cpp
Object object{0, 0, "dummy"};
```

and try to insert in a table

```cpp
auto id1 = storage.insert(object);
```

I get an exception.

How can I insert an object to this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in one issue in GitHub for [SQLite ORM](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm), projects with a [Composite key title](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm/issues/18#issuecomment-331165795) the method, for inserting an object with a composite key you must use the `replace` function instead of the `insert` function like below.

Consider you have an *entity* like below:

```cpp
struct Object
{
    int key_part_1;
    int key_part_2;
    std::string name;
};
```

And create a schema like below:

```cpp
auto storage = make_storage("test_remove.sqlite",
                            make_table("objects",
                                  make_column("key_part_1",
                                               &Object::key_part_1),
                                  make_column("key_part_2",
                                               &Object::key_part_2),
                                  make_column("name",
                                               &Object::name),
                                  primary_key(&Object::key_part_1, &Object::key_part_2)));
```

So you can insert one instance of this entity like below:

```cpp
Object object{0, 0, "Skillet"};

storage.replace(object);
```

Comment: I have the storage created within the body of a creator function. That is not longer in the current scope. How do I access storage in the class that is wrapping the features of interest?