# How to delete an entry in SQLite ORM with a composite key

Tags: c++, sqlite, orm

I am using the [SQLite ORM](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm) library for using SQLite in my program and I have a table like below:

```cpp
auto storage = make_storage("test_remove.sqlite",
                            make_table("objects",
                                       make_column("key_part_1",
                                                   &Object::key_part_1),
                                       make_column("key_part_2",
                                                   &Object::key_part_2),
                                       make_column("name",
                                                   &Object::name),
                                       primary_key(&Object::key_part_1, &Object::key_part_2)));
```

That, as you can see, this table has a composite key (`key_part_1` and `key_part_2`).

I see the [remove wiki page](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm/wiki/storage_t::remove), and, as you can see, there isn't any explicitly documentation about removing composite key objects, but it is saying if you want to remove an object with custom *where* conditions, use `remove_all` instead of *remove*.

How can I remove an object from this table effectively? Is there a better way that uses *remove_all*?

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/56074709/1539100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new [SQLite ORM](https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm) development branch, the creator of this library released a new API that is like below:

```cpp
remove(Ids... ids)
```

If you have an object like below:

```cpp
struct Object {
    int id;
    std::string name;
};
```

And have a composite key like below:

```cpp
auto storage = make_storage("",
                            make_table("objects",
                                       make_column("id", &Object::id),
                                       make_column("name", &Object::name),
                                       primary_key(&Object::id, &Object::name)));
```

With this API, you can remove an composite key object like below:

```cpp
        storage.remove<Object>(1, "Skillet");
```